# Emacs 24.3 IPython buffer - functions not returning values

Tags: emacs, ipython

Something strange is happening in my Emacs IPython buffer.

```
In [5]: def f(x):
   ...:     return x + 1

Display all 379 possibilities? (y or n)
   ...: 

In [9]: f(2)

In [10]:
```

However, if I define the function in one line (most of the time this can't reasonably be done!), then it works as expected.

```
In [16]: def f(x): return x + 1

In [17]: f(2)
Out[17]: 3
```

What's going on and how can I fix it?

Comment: Did you use RET or C-j to enter a new line and in the latter case did you indent with tabs or spaces ?

Comment: I used RET and am indenting with tabs.

Comment: mmmh. I don't need to indent, ipython does it for me. You are not using it inside ipdb are you ?

Comment: Seems TAB calls completion. Use C-j, which should do the indent and avoid the bug.

Comment: Hmm... I added some things (such as setting tab-width and indent-tabs-mode) to my `.emacs` and the problem when away.